# Disk Image Mounter equivalent fof Xubuntu

Tags: mount, xubuntu, iso, disk

I have mounted .iso files to install software with Nautilus' `Disk Image Mounter`.    I am interested in this functionality for Xubuntu 18.04 which is outfitted with the Thunar file manager.

Is there a similar utility or method to enable mounting the image to a fixed director, install software from disk1, unmount, mount disk 2, and finish the install?

Comment: Depending on the release of Xubuntu you are using (the later it is the more GTK+3 it uses), the cost of adding Nautilus and using tools you already know may not be very high. I love `thunar` but if it's easier in another file.manager I'll usually use another (or ctrl+alt+T & use commands)

Comment: Does disk image mounter just mount a file somewhere, or does it mount & install & then umount all automatically with just one click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GUI to mount disk images (iso, etc) in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537352/gui-to-mount-disk-images-iso-etc-in-xubuntu)

Comment: Related: [Where to find actual commands for Nautilus “open with” options?](https://askubuntu.com/q/481572/37165)

Answer (score 2):

My XFCE has Disks (`gnome-disk-utility`) installed, which includes `gnome-disk-image-mounter`.

Right-clicking on an .iso file in Thunar has the option to 'Open with "Disk Image Mounter"' (which doesn't mount but creates a loop device for the .iso file, but it then shows up in the DEVICES menu to click-to-mount & browse).

It [looks like the same tool that Nautilus uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/nautilus-mount-iso-file-with-right-click-menu), but without the rest of Nautilus.

---

Or, you might be able to create a custom mount command for Thunar's Open With -> Open With Other Application... and use a little shell script to `mkdir` / `mktemp -d` a mount point, then `mount %F tempdir`...

Comment: It works on Xubuntu 20.04. After installing `gnome-disk-utility`, new option shows up to mount disk images directly from Thunar open with menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it from a command line:

```
[sudo] mount -o loop the_disk_image the_mount_point
```

Comment: The `-o loop` option should be unnecessary now